# Why can there be a pointer to an object of a non-specified template class (without actual type used being specified)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I have a question somewhat related to an exercise i'm doing on binary trees. We already have some code given, and that code led to my question.

```
template <typename nodetype> class node {
public:
    //some functions like constructor and getData() etc.
private:
    node* leftptr;
    nodetype data;
    node* rightptr;
}

template <typename treetype> class tree {
public:
    //many other functions
    insertNode(treetype &value) {
        insertNodeHelper(rootptr, value);
    }
    insertNodeHelper(node<treetype>* & curptr, treetype &value) {
        //recursive function that compares value-parameter to curptr-node-value, then goes either left or right one node deeper, or if you cant to go deeper left or right, creates new node where you are) 
    }
private:
    node<nodetype>* rootptr;
}
```

In the tree-template's insertNodeHelper-function's parameter list, it says " node< treetype >* curptr ". I find the inclusion of the treetype-specification(1)  logical, because there is no class "node", so there can  never be an object of this class, and therefore also no pointer to any such object, right?
However I do not understand why there is no need for any such specification in the data elements of the node-class itself (e.g. it says `node* leftptr` as opposed to `node< nodetype > *leftptr`)? Because you are mentioning the classgroup/template defined while writing the definition, is it just implicitly assumed that you mean whatever actual class is used? (E.g. if the template is actually used for an int-type class , the compiler would automatically change "`node* leftptr`" to "`node<int>* leftptr`")?
Thanks in advance for any help.

(1) inlucision of treetype-specifier = " node< treetype >* curptr " as opposed to just " node* curptr "

Comment: Ok, thanks. But i could also include a node<int>*n as a data-element in every node, or? (irrespective of the type used in the class-definition, e.g. in the definition of a string-node).   
So the current implementation (/syntax) in C++ is basically just a comfort feature, but doesn't actually add or reduce any capabilities?

Comment: Yes, you could write out `node<int>* n` instead of `node* n`. It's just some nice sugar. Things can get extremely unreadable if you have complicated template arguments otherwise.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer. (My question is now solved.)